# SOLR: "&" character filtered by ICUTokenizer?

Tags: apache, solr

I am using ICUTokenizer on a field having multi-lingual names. The multi-lingual fields seem to working all fine, except that "&" character is filtered out. We have multiple & characters in the indexed field. Is there a way to tell ICU not to filter in using some script files (or similar solution)? 
Also Is ICUTokenizer enough for handling multi-lingual fields, or can u suggest some other way around it?